# Media queries in CSS not working in between devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I used the Responsive Web Designer add-on in Chrome to check out put targeting
320 x 480, 480 x 320, 600 x 800, 800 x 600, 768 x 1024, and 1024 x 768.

I used:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){ my code }
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){ my code }
```

...structure to make those site responsive.

When I check those layout it nicely working the browser. When I get a real device like Samsung Galaxy Core Prime in portrait mode, it shows me nicely. But, in landscape mode it is not giving me the alignment properly.

Also, when I check for my site from another device which has 360 width view port size screen the media queries which I have written for 480 are not effecting that.

I'd like the code which I wrote for 480 to apply to a device in between 320 and a 480 device.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You need to show your code, provide JSfiddle to look in to it.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Answer (score 0):

`@media screen` will work only on the specific screens so some devices with different sizes may skip

Use this instead

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px){ my code }
@media all and (max-width: 320px){ my code }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width 321px){ my code }
@media all and (max-width: 320px){ my code }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.